# How to clear a defined section in blade.php

Tags: php, laravel-blade

I'm aware that [Laravel-blade allows us to define sections of code](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/blade#stacks), but I'm wondering if it's possible to clear, or redefine a section within the same file as where it's been defined.

For example, something like:

```
@section('scripts')
    <script src="/example.js"></script>
@endsection


//something like
@section('scripts')
    // nothing
@endsection



// now the 'scripts' stack is an empty block of code.


 //print
 {{  @yield('scripts')  }}
```

Comment: In the same file? What's the use of that? You first push into the stack and then clear it? Why push at first then?

Comment: thanks, asked the wrong question. shouldve been sections instead.

Comment: What would be the purpose of this clearing? What are you actually looking to achieve?

Comment: I've been tasked with translating a twig file..
There is a view, which requires multiple files to be injected. 

How it's working is that there's a loop, which loops through a bunch of other files in various directories. 
in twig, these are being iported with an include statement inside a block, as the loop progresses. Twig automatically redefines the include statement-block, whereas I'm having trouble with redefining a 'block'/ (section) equivalent for blade.

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a way to do it, by simply using `ob_start()` in regular php instead.

```
        @php
            ob_start();
        @endphp
            // write blade code here
        @php
            $scripts = ob_get_contents();
            ob_end_clean();
        @endphp
        
          //print
         {!! $scripts !!}
```